# Trigger form submit automatically on partial/controller load

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a user log into my AngularJS app and once they do a http.get retreives a dataset with some key values. One of those is a key that I need to post to a iframe to get it queued up for the right user (based on the key). Thus far I have this and it is not working.

HTML:

```
<form name="watchLiveForm" action="{{testingUrl}}" target="watch-live" method="post" ng-submit="controllsubmit()">
  <label for="key">Company Software Key:</label>
  <input type="text" name="key" id="key" ng-model="key">

  <input type="submit">
 </form>
 <iframe name="watch-live" ng-src="{{testingUrl}}" width="100%" height="600">    </iframe>
```

Controller:

```
app = angular.module('angularWebApp.indexController', []);

app.controller('indexController', function($scope, $http, $rootScope, $sce) {

  $scope.controllsubmit = function() {
    console.log("I was called!");
  };

  if($scope.user !== undefined) {
    if($scope.user.software_key.constructor === Array) {
      $http.get('http://URL/api/' + $scope.user.software_key[1] + '/remotes').
      success(function(data) {
        if(data.id === 'error') {
          console.log(data);
        } else {
          $scope.machineList = data;
          $scope.key = $scope.user.software_key[1];
          console.log($scope.user.software_key[1]);
          console.log($scope.key);
          $scope.testing = 'http://URL/settings';
          $scope.testingUrl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl($scope.testing);
        }
      }).
      error(function(data) {
        alert(data);
      });
    }
  }

});
```

Directive:

```
angular.module('angularWebApp.indexDirectives', [])
.directive('form', function() {
    return {
        require: 'form',
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
            var scopa = element.scope();
            if (attributes.name && scopa[attributes.name]) {
                scopa[attributes.name].$submit = function() {
                    // Parse the handler of submit & execute that.
                    var fn = $parse(attr.ngSubmit);
                    $scope.$apply(function() {
                        fn($scope, {$event: e});
                    });
                };
            }
        }
    };
});
```

After the user is logged in I call a http.get and obtain the software_key which I pass to the form (works). It just seems that getting the form to automatically submit is the issue as I want to made the inputs hidden eventually so they will not see the form as they do now. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: you can define function in controller , and write it's calling after it without any checks or conditions.So every time the controller is loaded , the function will be called automatically, isn't?

Comment: I am unsure what you are talking about @RishiPrakash. I apologize I should have mentioned I am still learning and quite new. Can you extrapolate?